# Implementing a particular feature with ruby on rails: allowing users to edit other users' text line by line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, model, data-representation

I'm new to RoR and  I've read some Ruby on Rails books and tutorials that were very helpful, but at last I'm working on a feature that seems to be beyond the depth of the books and tutorials as it is rather quite a specific feature.

I would like other users to be able to provide correction for a user's post on a sentence by sentence basis. So other users can mark a particular sentence as correct, or provide correction and additional comments. The original user will then be able to view a separate post of the corrected text with comments beside each sentence.

Right now, I have created an entry model and users are already able to post their texts, but I'm not sure how to implement this correction system. Do I need to create another model for each sentence for correction and if so, how should I go about doing that? Any advice would be immensely appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is this prose text or a more structured format like code?

Comment: it would be prose text!

Comment: Hi Wu, you might wanna look at this thread : https://dev.to/ben/how-would-you-build-a-medium-esque-highlighting-feature-7oj to understand the implementation details.

Comment: This might be better suited on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/